# How are pods in completed Kubernetes jobs deleted?

Tags: kubernetes

I'm running a Kubernetes job, and was trying to look at the logs for it hours after it had been completed. However, when I did `kubectl describe job [jobname]`, no pods were listed (`Events` came back as just `<none>`), and when I did `kubectl get pods`, the pod for that job was not there. How would the deletion of pods in completed jobs be configured, and how could I change that to let the pod stay up longer so I can read its logs?

Comment: Hi, Here is the mechanism https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/jobs-run-to-completion/#ttl-mechanism-for-finished-jobs

Comment: The linked docs specifically state they are not removed by default. Can you edit the question to show the job manifest being submitted?

Comment: Yea, I have a similar thought, TTL mechanism will delete notonly pods but also the jobs.

Comment: can you check if the field is set or not `ttlSecondsAfterFinished` in the jobSpec ?

Comment: @SureshVishnoi `ttlSecondsAfterFinished` isn't there so there must be something else deleting the pods

Comment: is it a cronjob ? as there is also a capacity-based cleanup policy.

Comment: Can you post the job yaml?

Answer (score 1):

Look at the properties below.  Below setting would keep 3 jobs in the history that were successful. You would have one failed job history. You can change the count as per your need

```
successfulJobsHistoryLimit: 3
failedJobsHistoryLimit: 1
```